# Reflex to mean a curved shape

Tags: meaning

Growing up I was taught two meanings of *reflex*:

1. The unconscious reaction to stimulus (n)
2. An angle greater than 180° but less than 360° (adj)

However, I've also come across *reflex* used in the context of a [aerofoil profile](https://dudek.eu/en/profil-samostateczny/):

[image: reflex paramotor wing]

And for the [shape of an archery bow](https://www.reddit.com/r/Bowyer/comments/nx4ukk/categorizing_bow_shapes_based_on_unstrung_shape/):

[image: reflex bow shape]

Are these two usages related and what is the etymology of using *reflex* in this way? I haven't been able to find any dictionaries including this usage.

Comment: [Reflex](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/reflex) is a common word for things that are reflected or bent back or away, e.g. reflex cameras, reflex bows, reflex sights. reflex speakers, anti-reflex coating, etc. [Reflex](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=reflex) is from the Latin meaning "bending back" as I'm sure you know. The etymology of individual things like bows will require separate answers as to precisely how a thing acquired the name, what it is that bends back, how it differs from other things that bend or don't bend, etc.

Comment: That aerofoil text has mistakes in it. Anyway, Reflex means that the trailing edge of the aerofoil is higher than the leading edge, moving the centre of pressure forward. This makes a reflex wing extremely pitch stable and resistant to collapse. https://parajet.com/us/new-pilots/choosing-your-paramotor-wing/

Comment: I oppose the vote to close. The definition of "bent [backwards]" is missing from most dictionaries other than as the verb "to reflex" where it is occasionally appears as "To bend, turn, or fold back; to recurve"